# ImportError: No module named rospkg

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

I was trying to follow the tutorials under rosserial_arduino from this link:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World

But I have gotten an error message for this command:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I got following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sanket/ros_workspace/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/serial_node.py", line 38, in <module>
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest("rosserial_python")
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
from roslib.launcher import load_manifest
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 42, in <module>
import rospkg
ImportError: No module named rospkg
```

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44356/importerror:-no-module-named-rospkg/) by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 234 on 2012-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This specific error should be resolved by installing rospkg.  On Ubuntu install python-rospkg via apt.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1